# Accusations of answer stealing

Tags: discussion

How should one respond to another user accusing you of stealing an answer and reposting it under your account, even though you spent the effort to figure it out for yourself and they just beat you to the punch?

[Question in reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354816/jquery-tr-click-input-radio-checked/17354884?noredirect=1#comment25183626_17354884)

The first answering member basically accuses me of stealing his answer even though I was firstly cleaning up the post with formatting and capitalization corrections and *then* working on my answer. I don't much appreciate being called a liar.

Comment: Well, five minutes is kind of a long time.  How long does it take to write an answer that short?  Next time, write your answer first, and *then* clean up the question.

Comment: If you didn't steal the answer, there is little to be gained by engaging in such a dialog. Either delete yours as a duplicate or improve it.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, yes you are correct. I really just have a big issue with being called a liar.

Comment: Did you not notice the other answer before composing yours? If not, you might mention that in a comment.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please refrain from voting on the two answers being discussed here just because you saw this question on Meta.  Cast your votes based on the answers' relative merits, if you wish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is entirely possible that two people can come up with the exact same answer, especially when the answer is short and involves copy/pasting code from the question.

I have had this happen to me in the past, and I have ended up deleting my answer because there is no point having two virtually identical answers. It can be a loss of rep, but so what - you can simply answer another question. Seize the opportunity to be the bigger man ;)

In this case I would also flag the comments, they are inflammatory and not necessary. Your deleted answer is still visible to people with >10K rep, but the comments are deleted permanently so they won't be visible on the deleted answer.

Comment: Ok. Deleted. Comments flagged. Move on with my life.

Comment: (by the way mods can see deleted comments @slugster.)

Comment: @Doorknob I know - I am a mod on another SE site. They are not immediately visible, we have to click to bring them up in a new window. The key thing with deleting the comments is that no regular users would see them ever again, even if they were >10K.